# React lazy load image in a component that is passed image source as a property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, lazy-loading, create-react-app

I have a React app created with `create-react-app`. It contains the standard `src/` directory and I have created a `src/assets/home/` directory where I have saved image files that I intend to use in my project. I am not sure how to get the image referencing correctly within components in my app.

I have the following component that I pass a set of properties whose path is `src/scenes/Home/InfographicSection/InfographicBlock/InfographicBlock.js`:

```
        <InfographicBlock
            title="Some Title"
            description="some text"
            imgPath="../../../../assets/home/home-logo.png"
        />
```

The InfographicBlock uses the library `react-lazyload` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload):

```
import React from 'react';
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazyload';

const InfographicBlock = (props) => (
        <div className="infographic-block columns">

        <LazyLoad height={200}>
            <img src={require(`${props.imgPath}`)} alt="" />
        </LazyLoad>

            <div className="content-container column">
                <h2 className="subtitle">{props.title}</h2>
                <p>{props.description}</p>
            </div>

        </div>
);

export default InfographicBlock;
```

The image referencing works great if I add the string path directly to the image tag like so:

```
<img src={ require('../../../../assets/home/home-logo.png') } />
```

However seeing as this is a component, I want to pass in the property as a variable to reuse the component.

I have tried variations of this without success:

```
<img src={require(`${props.imgPath}`)} alt="" />
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What i did was import the image first.

```
import product1 from './Images/female_sport3.jpg'

<ProductPage currency={currency} currencyRate={currencyRate} product1={product1}></ProductPage>
```

Inside ProductPage.js

```
const {currency, currencyRate, product1} = props
<img src={product1} alt=""></img>
```

This is the reference for import image: https://www.edwardbeazer.com/importing-images-with-react/

Comment: Thank you for the reply - and yes importing image I have done this way before - but how can I LAZY LOAD the image with the component in the example code? If I import the image doesn't it defeat the purpose? Or is your code lazy loading anyway? Thanks.

Comment: I do not use lazy load inside my code. 

I import the image in index.js then i pass this image as variable to ProductPage.js.

Comment: Right but my question is specifically about using image reference string with lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

So you can import the image inside your `ParentComponent`

```
import React from 'react';
// import the image
import myImage from "../assets/images/myImage.png";

const ParentComponent = (props) => (
  <ChildComponent imageUrl={myImage}/>
);

export default ParentComponent;
```

And in the `ChildComponent`

```
import React from 'react';
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazyload';

const ChildComponent = (props) => (
        <div className="infographic-block columns">

        <LazyLoad height={200}>
            <img src={props.imageUrl} alt="" />
        </LazyLoad>

            <div className="content-container column">
                <h2 className="subtitle">{props.title}</h2>
                <p>{props.description}</p>
            </div>

        </div>
);

export default ChildComponent;
```

I would also recommend you to use - [react-lazy-load-image-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-load-image-component) package it's syntactically pleasing and has better functionality

Using `'react-lazyload'`

```
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazyload';
<LazyLoad height={200}>
    <img src={props.imageUrl} alt="" />
</LazyLoad>
```

Using `'react-lazy-load-image-component'`

```
import { LazyLoadImage } from "react-lazy-load-image-component";
import 'react-lazy-load-image-component/src/effects/blur.css';
<LazyLoadImage className="w-full" src={props.imageUrl} alt="" effect="blur" width="30vw" height="40vh"/>
```

You could also add placeholder image or effects like blur while loading the image.

I hope I understood and answered your question properly!